# A faster implementation for Math.abs(a - b) - Math.abs(c - d)?

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization

I have a Java method that repeatedly evaluates the following expression in a very tight loop with a large number of repetitions:

```
Math.abs(a - b) - Math.abs(c - d)
```

`a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are `long` values that can span the whole range of their type. They are different in each loop iteration and they do not satisfy any invariant that I know of.

The profiler indicates that a significant portion of the processor time is spent in this method. While I *will* pursue other avenues of optimization first, I was wondering if there is a smarter way to calculate the aforementioned expression.

Apart from inlining the `Math.abs()` calls manually for a very slight (if any) performance gain, is there any mathematical trick that I could use to speed-up the evaluation of this expression?

Comment: If the values span the whole range of their type, you will have plenty of overflows with this code if, for example, a is a very large negative number and b is a very large positive number (or vice-versa). Check your algorithm.

Comment: @JBNizet: I have not yet encountered any overflows, so I suppose that is some sort of invariant. The `span the whole range` condition was mostly to avoid answers that assume that e.g. all variable fit in 32-bits.

Comment: note that such overflows will not cause any exception: only wrong calculated values. They might thus have been unnoticed.

Comment: @JBNizet: I do know that integer overflows are silent - I am mostly a C programmer :-) I have a test harness using the results of known-good code as a reference. I am still looking for corner cases, but I have yet to encounter any issues.

Comment: @thkala Simple corner case: `a=-2^63; b=any positive value`. If your test harness isn't testing such numbers, better make absolutely sure such cases are impossible. Especially fun case: `a=-2^63; b = 0` - I do hope your algorithm can deal with cases where the result of Math.abs is negative!

Comment: @thkala Another idea might be that you don't even really need to do that computation. I know that doesn't sound particularly helpful, but if you could post some additional code revealing how this value is used, it could make much more aggressive optimization possible. Unless the point of the loop is to compute the value of |a-b|-|c-d|, it could be possible to implement it a different way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using this little method:

```
public static long diff(final long a, final long b, final long c, final long d) {
    final long a0 = (a < b)?(b - a):(a - b);
    final long a1 = (c < d)?(d - c):(c - d);

    return a0 - a1;
}
```

I experienced a measurable performance increase - about 10-15% for the whole application. I believe this is mostly due to:

- *The elimination of a method call:* Rather than calling `Math.abs()` twice, I call this method once. Sure, static method calls are not inordinately expensive, but they still have an impact.
- *The elimination of a couple of negation operations:* This may be offset by the slightly increased size of the code, but I'll happily fool myself into believing that it actually made a difference.

**EDIT:**

It seems that it's actually the other way around. Explicitly inlining the code does not seem to impact the performance in my micro-benchmark. Changing the way the absolute values are calculated does...

Comment: Your first point is unimportant. The JIT inlines such simple calls anyway - you can easily test that by putting your logic into a function and calling it, no different in time (and good practice too ;) ). The second point seems to be valid though - I get about 10% speedup in a micro benchmark (can post code, but yes I'm observing OSR, warmup and all that!)

Comment: @Voo: true, my benchmark had an *issue* with a counter that would not count, thus skewing the results.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the profiler isn't giving you a true result as it trying to profile (and thus adding over head to) such a trivial "method".  Without the profile Math.abs can be turned into a small number of machine code instructions, and you won't be able to make it faster than that.

I suggest you do a micro-benchmark to confirm this.  I would expect loading the data to be an order of magnitude more expensive.

```
long a = 10, b = 6, c = -2, d = 3;

int runs = 1000 * 1000 * 1000;
long start = System.nanoTime();
for (int i = 0; i < runs; i += 2) {
    long r = Math.abs(i - a) - Math.abs(c - i);
    long r2 = Math.abs(i - b) - Math.abs(d - i);
    if (r + r2 < Integer.MIN_VALUE) throw new AssertionError();
}
long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
System.out.printf("Took an average of %.1f ns per abs-abs. %n", (double) time / runs);
```

prints

```
Took an average of 0.9 ns per abs-abs.
```

Comment: It's definitely possible, although I think that the loop is tight enough to be indicative. BTW, are you sure that there is such an instruction for 64-bit integers on x86_64?

Comment: Hmmmm, It has `movabs` but that doesn't appear to do what I thought.

Comment: That's actually testing the Interpreter performance (the JIT itself recognizes that the loop can be optimized away it seems - running this test several times returns `178, 176, 0, 0, 0,..` for me.

Comment: Hoisting the variables outside the method seems to work fine: `mean=185ms, var=13ms` for 100 test runs with 100million loop iterations each.

Answer (score 1):

You can always try to unroll the functions and hand optimize, if you don't get more cache misses it might be faster.

If I got the unrolling right it could be something like this:

```
    if(a<b)
{
    if(c<d)
    {
        r=b-a-d+c;
    }
    else
    {
        r=b-a+d-c;
    }
}
else
{
    if(c<d)
    {
        r=a-b-d+c;
    }
    else
    {
        r=a-b+d-c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sure its the method itself causes the problem? Maybe its an enormous amount of invocation of this method and you just see the aggregated results (like TIME_OF_METHOD_EXECUTION X NUMBER_OF_INVOCATIONS) in your profiler?